# how can I set background image dynamically?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, background, src

I have a div in my page with class="post-first", in this div there are multiple images which I don't know what they may be!! I just want when I hover on this div, the first image comes on background.below shows what I did.no answer!!thanks for help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.post-first').mouseover(function(){
  var a=$('img')[0].src;
  alert(a);
  $(this).css('background-image','url(a)');
  $(this).css('background-color','#F00')
  })
});
```

```css
.post-first{
 background-color:#039;
 display:inline-block;
 height:13em;
 margin-left:4px;
 padding:4px
}
div.post-first img{
 opacity:0
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-first">
<h3>[cb:post_title]</h3><br />
[cb:post_body1]
<img src="http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.607986701601669353&pid=1.7"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate variable value, it is currently evaluated as string and being rendered as:

```
background-image: url("a")
```

change it to this:

```
$(this).css('background-image', "url('"+a+"')");
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/wps7bn5s/